# HtmlAgilityPack Div Class Contains String

Tags: html-agility-pack

I'm trying to scrape only article text from web pages.   I have discovered that the article is always surrounded with div tags.  Unfortunately the class of these div tags is slightly different for each web page.  I looked into using XPath but I don't think it will work due to the different class names.  Is there a way I can get all the div tags and then get the class?

Examples

```
<div class="entry_single">
  <p>I recently traveled without my notebook for the first time in ages.</p>
</div>

<div class="entry-content-pagination">
  <p>Ward 9 Ald. Steven Dove</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That'd be easier using Linq.

```
foreach(HtmlNode div in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div"))
{
    string className = div.GetAttributeValue("class", string.Empty);
    // do something with class name
}
```